# drawing a circle in the middle of a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, I put the circle in the middle of the line by trial and error. Is there a code to do this automatically.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (4,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {$X$};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,3) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {$P$};
\draw [thick, green!40!black] (.78,.47)  -- +(45:3.3cm) node [green!40!black, xshift=.2cm, yshift=.2cm] {$S$};
\draw[blue,fill=blue] (1.95,1.65) circle (2.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw [thick, green!40!black] (.78,.47)  -- +(45:3.3cm) 
node[midway,circle,draw,fill=blue] {}
node [green!40!black, xshift=.2cm, yshift=.2cm] {$S$};`

Comment: where can I put the code for the size of the circle  (2.5pt)

Comment: You can put `minimum width=2.5pt`. Note that nodes cannot be made arbitrarily small that way, but you can then shrink them with scale, e.g. `minimum width=10pt,scale=0.1`.

Comment: The scale option is working, but the minimum width option does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but one way is to define names for the coordinates and then use TikZ's `calc` library: `($(A)!0.5!(S)$)` which says to go to the coordinate that is `0.5` along the path from `(A)` to `(S)`. The coordinates `(A)` and `(S)` were defined as the drawing of the line was done:

```
\draw [thick, green!40!black] 
        (.78,.47) coordinate (A)  
    -- +(45:3.3cm) coordinate (S)
```

[image]

Alternatively you could place a `node` on the path at `pos=0.5`.

```
\draw [thick, green!40!black] (.78,.47)  -- +(45:3.3cm) 
    node [midway, draw=red, fill=red, shape=circle, minimum size=5.0pt, inner sep=0pt] {}
    node [green!40!black, xshift=.2cm, yshift=.2cm] {$S$};
%\draw[blue,fill=blue] (1.95,1.65) circle (2.5pt);
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (4,0) node [black, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {$X$};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,3) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {$P$};
\draw [thick, green!40!black] 
    (.78,.47) coordinate (A)  
    -- +(45:3.3cm) coordinate (S)
    node [green!40!black, xshift=.2cm, yshift=.2cm] {$S$}
;
\draw[blue,fill=blue] ($(A)!0.5!(S)$) circle (2.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using my code (not the coordinate method), how can I insert the circle code (with all its color definitions and size) (blue,fill=blue , 2.5pt) placed as a node on the path at pos=0.5

Comment: I used the option pos=0.5 instead of the option midway, as suggested in the above comment; both work fine.

Comment: @Hany:  Code update to show how to use a node.  Also, `pos=0.5` is the equivalent to `midway`. However, should you decide to change the position later, using the `pos=` is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

an alternative:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, thick,
dot/.style = {circle, fill=blue, minimum size=6pt, inner sep=0pt, node contents={}}
                        ]
\draw [-latex](0,0) -- (4,0) node [right] {$X$};
\draw [-latex](0,0) -- (0,3) node [above] {$P$};
\draw [green!40!black]
    (.78,.47) -- node[dot] +(45:3.3cm) node [pos=1.1] {$S$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]